# Double spend trying to use cold signing

Tags: transaction-failed

I'm creating transactions in my watch-only wallet and signing them in my offline wallet but each time the transaction is rejected with the message "double spend, invalid input".  I haven't been able to spend anything yet as all of my transactions have been rejected.  Any ideas why I'm getting this error message?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you're trying to spend outputs which are already spent.
The cold wallet has no access to the blockchain, so you have to tell it which outputs are spent, in this order:

"export_outputs filename" in the hot wallet
"import_outputs filename" in the cold wallet
"export_key_images filename" in the cold wallet
"import_key_images filename" in the hot wallet

Normally this is done automatically as part of the transaction creation system, but if you make any transaction otherwise (or fail to save your wallet after doing something), then it'll go out of sync and you have to do it manually.